# Sending object through http.Post() not working

Tags: garrys-mod

So, I'm trying to send an object through the parameters argument in http.Post() (see https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/http/Post) but the server isn't receiving anything in the body of the request.

I also need this to work using application/json instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded for the Header Content-Type. I think this is where the problem is, as it feels like it is treating the request as if it was using application/x-www-form-urlencoded even when I specify otherwise.

And also, sorry if I sound confused - I probably am.

```lua
    local data = { 
        fields = { 
            ['name']= { ['stringValue'] ="Bob"}, 
            ['age'] = { ['stringValue'] ="19"} 
        } 
    }

    local header = {
        ['Content-Type']= 'application/json'
    }

    http.Post(
        "https://en00ot5pylxlbg.x.pipedream.net",
        (data), 
        function( result ) 
            print("IT WORKED " .. result)
        end, 
        function( fail ) 
            print("IT DIDNT WORK " .. fail)
        end, 
        header
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I worked it out.

If you want to post json, do something like this:

```lua
HTTP({
        url= YOUR_URL_ENDPOINT, 
        method= "POST", 
        headers= { 
            ['Content-Type']= 'application/json'
        },
        success= function( code, body, headers ) 
            print("IT WORKED " .. body)
        end, 
        failed = function( err ) 
            print("IT DIDNT WORK " .. err)
        end,
        body=util.TableToJSON(data)
})
```